# Why ocelot doesn't replace parts of header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, ocelot

I use Ocelot for api gateway and encountered problem with configuration. I'm trying to replace part of the 'Location' header value that comes from api (when api returns `CreatedAtRoute(...)` result).
See part of **ocelot.json**:

```
// ...
{
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/hotels",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post", "Put" ],
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "<api_host>",
      "Port": 80
    }
  ],
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/hotels",
  "DownstreamHeaderTransform": {
    "Location": "{DownstreamBaseUrl}/api, {BaseUrl}" // the issue here
  }
},
// ...
```

What I want in headers when posting new object (42 is just random number):

```
Location: http://<gateway_host>/hotels/42
```

What I actually get:

```
Location: http://<api_host>/api/hotels/42
```

May be it doesn't matter but both apps are running in docker.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to emphasize it happens also using **regular process run - not only in docker** environment.

The request I use is POST to:
`https://localhost:7051/api/project-manager/examples?exampleName=example1`
(`/api/project-manager` is a prefix that Ocelot adds).
and the (bad) location returned to Ocelot's client is `https://localhost:2261/examples/example1` same as I got when tried directly to the web api without the GW:

```
 content-length: 2868 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Mon,01 Aug 2022 11:27:23 GMT 
 location: https://localhost:2261/examples/example1 
 server: Kestrel
```

While I have expected to get location: `https://localhost:7051/api/project-manager/examples/example1`

The lack is in both - **port** and the **path** transformation: the `/api/project-manager` prefix ocelot is configured to add.

---

**As for the solution,**
I saw another discussion which provides a solution.
So this discussion might be a duplication of:
[How add Gateway base path on CreatedAtRoute Location Header - URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203556/how-add-gateway-base-path-on-createdatroute-location-header-url-rewrite)

It helped in my case by adding the following **DownstreamHeaderTransform** to config:

```
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/project-manager/{everything}",
      "DownstreamHeaderTransform": {
        "Location": "{DownstreamBaseUrl}, {BaseUrl}/api/project-manager"
      },
```

Which produced a correct (transformed) location:

```
 access-control-allow-origin: * 
 content-length: 2864 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Tue,02 Aug 2022 07:52:25 GMT 
 location: https://localhost:7051/api/project-manager/examples/example1 
 server: Kestrel
```